# How to run machine-specific tests during DevOps remote build

Tags: unit-testing, .net, team-foundation-server, devops

What are the generally accepted means of running tests that pass on the dev machine on the build server where they'll consistently fail due to missing dependencies? (In this case, a configuration file that is managed by another completely external application.)

My app is reading an INI file containing various key/value pairs, and I'm storing the path to that file in `App Settings`. This works fine in my dev environment and in production as well.

But what about when I send all of this to TFS for a build? Those tests are going to fail because neither the INI file nor the `Path` setting pointing to it exist on the server (nor do I think they should, but I may be mistaken with this).

To quote [Jon](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/348548/132017):

> Typically a build machine is meant for build, compile + unit tests.
>   There should be no external dependencies.

Should I include logic to just skip those particular tests if they're not running in dev?

**--EDIT--**

I have three working environments:

1. Dev (my workstation)
2. Build/Test (a TFS instance running on my server)
3. Production (the application running at the customer site)

The app has a UI for specifying the path to the INI file. This path is stored in `App Settings`, which in turn is stored in a subfolder under `%AppData%` (in Windows). The file is created and updated by an external application whose source code is not under my control.

Tests succeed in Dev and Prod, but fail in Build due to the fact that neither the INI file nor the `Path` setting pointing to it exist in Build.

According to my research, external dependencies (like this INI file and its corresponding setting) should not be introduced in a Build environment. I tend to agree. It seems small now with just this one instance, but I can easily foresee this spiraling out of control as more such scenarios are introduced.

It wouldn't take much of this before Build became choked down with all of these specialized, tightly coupled, brittle and difficult-to-maintain configurations.

How do we get out of this Catch-21?

Comment: You're making me dizzy. I'm hearing: dev=pass, build server=fail, dev=fine, production=fine, TFS=?, candied_orange=huh? Please pick some consistent terms to use and make their meaning and what's going on clear.

Comment: @candied_orange—TFS is Microsoft's build server—among other things not relevant for this topic—thus the tag. Environments: `dev=development`, `prod=production`. I'm using what I believe so far is ubiquitous terminology in our world. Lord knows, I don't want you to get dizzy :-) Can I clarify anything else?

Comment: My problem isn't the abbreviations. It's understanding what your problem actually is. I suspect you're saying the same thing different ways and are causing confusion by doing that. Please edit the question to make your situation clear.

Comment: You say your environments are dev and prod. I'm trying to get you to be clear about the other environment. The one in which it's failing. You've mentioned "DevOps remote build", "build server", and "Team Foundation Server". If these are three different ways to talk about the same test environment (that for some mysterious reason you think can't be allowed to have the ini file dev and prod have) please edit the question to make that clear.

Comment: Why in the hell are your tests touching any INI files? Those should be mocked out.

Comment: @Euphoric ~ Probably because I wrote them that way ;-) Seriously, though... I'm having a hard time getting my head around mocking. Or rather, whether it's a wise thing to do at all. It strikes me as building a fake world to emulate the real one. Since we've created that fake world, it's subject to bugs just the same as the code under test. It's very possible, in fact I'd say probable, that we might go on our merry way, passing tests and thinking all is well, when the mock is flawed. That said, these particular tests are touching the INI file because I need to test the code that manipulates it.

Comment: @Euphoric ~ I'm not defending this as something on which I'm immovable... in essence I guess I'm asking for your rebuttal. I want to learn what this stuff is all about, but at the same time I must raise my observations as I go.

Comment: @candied_orange ~ I've edited my question. Does that help clarity at all?

Comment: Here we go again... yet another lazy, cowardly drive-by-downvoter slips away into the shadows. This is one of the worst problems at SE; the ability to downvote without comment. It's absolutely anti-community improvement. Want to be of real assistance to someone? If you're going to downvote, SAY WHY! How rude. It's just insulting. Trouble is, the jerk who did it will never see my admonition.

Comment: @candied_orange ~ Are these the clarifications you were looking for?

Comment: @InteXX yes they are

Comment: @candied_orange ~ OK, good.

Comment: @Euphoric ~ What would you suggest as an alternative that satisfies all of these concerns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its best to design your program so that it is able to run after it's built.

In this case you need a default path in app settings, pretty easy, and a default ini file to be copied to that path.

Include these things in the project and if necessary add post build steps to move them to the right path or what have you.

Alternatively, you might consider these test Integration tests. In which case, don't run them immediately after build. (Skip them by adding categories to your tests, so you have unit and integration) First deploy the program to your test environment with another automated step (Octopus deploy?) and *then* run them.

Comment: I like this way of looking at things. I believe this may be the answer I seek, but I want to wait a bit before accepting it. Do you mind? @candied_orange may want to answer as well.

Comment: `Octopus deploy?` FYI I'm using TFS Release Tasks for deployment.